# PHONEGAP Camera option on input file

Tags: cordova, camera, file-io

I'm using phonegap.

I Want upload files, so I used that:

it works on web browser, when click open a window with file explorer and camera.

In phonegap app only open file explorer..

I try use a pluggin to camera, I can only put GetPicture function associated with a button, and have another button for the input ...

What I need is to have a button for uploading via either camera and file browser...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any luck with this? I have the same problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't choose camera in file upload in cordova application on android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26381050/cant-choose-camera-in-file-upload-in-cordova-application-on-android)