# webview open camera from input field without filechooser

Tags: java, android, android-webview

My personal app is almost done, which is to press on the input field, make a photo with the camera and upload it to the external php server. The last part works fine. I just can't get it to work how I want it to work. When I press on the input field in the webview (external source) i'm getting the menu called "Image Chooser" with the options: Camera & Documents. I want to get the Camera directly when pressing on the input field.

[image]

This is my external html page which gets loaded by webview:

```
<form id="uploadimage"  action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" style="display: none;" id="upload_file" name="upload_file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
  <input type="submit" name='submit_image' id="clickme"  value="Upload Image"/>
 </form>
```

This is my MainActivity.java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    WebView webView;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String mCM;
    private ValueCallback mUM;
    private ValueCallback<Uri[]> mUMA;
    private final static int FCR=1;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            Uri[] results = null;
            //Check if response is positive
            if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK){
                if(requestCode == FCR){
                    if(null == mUMA){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(intent == null || intent.getData() == null){
                        //Capture Photo if no image available
                        if(mCM != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                        }
                    }else{
                        String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                        if(dataString != null){
                            results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
            mUMA = null;
        }else{
            if(requestCode == FCR){
                if(null == mUM) return;
                Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
                mUM.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUM = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetJavaScriptEnabled", "WrongViewCast"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.medion.panningen.logphoto.R.layout.activity_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(com.medion.panningen.logphoto.R.id.ifView);
        assert webView != null;
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21){
            webSettings.setMixedContentMode(0);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
        webView.loadUrl("http://localhost/mobile/photo/index2.php");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){

            //For Android 5.0+
            public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                    WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                    FileChooserParams fileChooserParams){
                if(mUMA != null){
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try{
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    }catch(IOException ex){
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if(photoFile != null){
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    }else{
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
                Intent[] intentArray;
                if(takePictureIntent != null){
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                }else{
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    public class Callback extends WebViewClient{
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed loading app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    // Create an image file
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException{
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "img_"+timeStamp+"_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return File.createTempFile(imageFileName,".jpg",storageDir);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event){
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode){
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if(webView.canGoBack()){
                        webView.goBack();
                    }else{
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

`Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);`

For this:

`Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer was not working for me in api 22 or lower. I solved it in the following

wayIntent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);

**----------->in this line, change contentSelectionIntent for takePictureIntent**
               chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
**<---------------------------------**

```
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
```

**-------------->coment this line**
             //   chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);**<-----------------**
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);

Comment: This will allow you to choose between several applications that use the camera